# StakeCredentialHash - Lucid

Tags: lucid

I'm having difficulties getting the StakeCredentialHash from a privatekey. Using lucid
At the moment i can get the paymentCredentialHash, but missing the stakeCredentialHash, i have to put it manualy.

```
  // Replace with the path to the bot's private key file
  const botPrivateKeyFilePath = "./wallets/wallet1.sk";
  // Read the bot's private key from the file
  const botPrivateKey = await Deno.readTextFile(botPrivateKeyFilePath);

  // Import the bot wallet using the private key
  const wallet = await lucid.selectWalletFromPrivateKey(botPrivateKey);

  // Get the paymentCredential hash from the wallet address
  const walletAddress = await lucid.wallet.address();
  const { paymentCredential } = lucid.utils.getAddressDetails(walletAddress);
  const paymentCredentialHash = paymentCredential?.hash;
```

How can i achieve this?